# C++ Generic Variable

Tags: c++

I'm trying create generic variable, something like this:

```
Class Foo {
    template<typename T>
    boost::unordered_map<int, T> items;

    template<typename T>
    boost::unordered_map<int, T>& get() {
          return items<T>;
    }
}

// ....
void main() {
    Foo foo;
    SomeClass d();
    foo.get<SomeClass>().insert(std::make_pair(1, d));
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to make a class for that? the map can return you the values easily enough already so why make a class containing a map? If you want to actually modify the class you need to return a reference or you'll just change the copy

Comment: @meneldal Because for every foo instance should be it's own unordered_maps

Comment: I guess it's possible using type erasure (and a map of maps) -- if you really need an arbitrary set of types.

Comment: `SomeClass d();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Your foo class makes it just more inconvenient to access the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by making the whole `Foo` class a template:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    using items_map_t = std::unordered_map<int, T>;

    items_map_t items;

    items_map_t& get() const
    {
        return items;
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't want to make whole foo class a template

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael Then how will the `items` member variable be instantiated? You can't have template member variable (or template variables at all) yet, though it comes with the proposed [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B1y#Variable_templates) standard, but I don't know how (or if) it will work with member variables.